# How to get a *.desktop file to launch the app, and to display the Name and app icon, on the Desktop and in /usr/share/applications/?

Tags: 18.04, permissions, launcher, .desktop, file-properties

Ubuntu Bionic Beaver 18.04.3
Nautilus 3.26.4 (Files)

*.desktop files on the Desktop, or in ~/bin appear with the *application* icon and the filename is replaced by the value of the file's Name key. Clicking the icon launches the associated app.

I have two files -- free42dec.desktop and free42bin.desktop -- to launch the Free42 emulation of the HP42s Reverse Polish calculator. But in Nautilus (Files), these files still show as their full filenames and the generic text icon, instead of as Free42 Decimal and Free42 Binary, with the appropriate calculator icons. Another oddity is that opening the Properties for these files just shows plain-vanilla in the Basic tab, but other correctly-behaving *.desktop files show the value of the Exec key in the Basic tab.

I won't have been the first to have this problem with *.desktop files, but no combination of search terms will give me the answer. I have tried various suggested remedies, but none work. So, in desperation, here is the text of one of these files (the other is similar):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=2.5.17
Name=Free42 Decimal
GenericName=Calculator
Comment=HP42s calculator using decimal number calculations.
Exec=free42dec -skin Realistic
Path=/usr/local/bin
Icon=/usr/share/icons/free42/free42dec.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;

##Define Actions
Actions=Quit;Free42_Binary;

[Desktop Action Quit]
Name=Quit
# Kill all free42bin or free42dec instances currently running
# Exec=pkill free42*
# Kill only free42dec instances
Exec=pkill free42dec
OnlyShowIn=Unity;

[Desktop Action Free42_Binary]
Name=Free42 Binary
# You can start the alternative calc from the right-click menu
Exec=free42bin -skin KD0GLS_Full
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

Can anyone see a fault with these files? I tried to find a parser or grammar checker, and the documentation was no help. There does not seem to be any special installer for *.desktop files.

Comment: To be clear, your issue is that you see the full file name in the file manager, where you expect to see the application name and icon?

Comment: Yes. Also, double-clicking the file in the Files manager does not launch the app. And the icon does not appear in the Unity/Gnome Launcher (the window that opens when you click the checkerboard icon in the bottom LH corner of the desktop.

Comment: Use Nemo, this is current Nautilus intended behavior

Comment: In 18.04, it still works but the desktopfile may need to be set executable and trusted. In 19.10, indeed, that behaviour has been removed altogether - .desktop files are revealed as their real self in the file manager (which it should i.m.h.o.)

Answer (score 1):

After even more research, I found out about the CLI command `desktop-file-validate`, which checks the syntax and structure of `*.desktop` files.

```
.../usr/share/applications$ desktop-file-validate free42dec.desktop
free42dec.desktop: error: file contains line "?[Desktop Entry]", which is not a comment, a group or an entry
```

Look at `"?[Desktop Entry]"`. That `?` indicates that there is hidden character preceding `[`, which turns out to be a byte-order mark (BOM) which indicates how this UTF-8 file is to be read by BigEndian and LittleEndian systems. More searching yields `dos2unix`, a utility that converts Windows text files to UNIX format, which you can get with

```
$ sudo apt install dos2unix
```

Now do this:

```
.../usr/share/applications$dos2unix free42dec.desktop
dos2unix: converting file free42dec.desktop to Unix format...
```

Yay! Now the `free42dec.desktop` file appears in Nautilus in `/usr/share/applications` with the `Name` key Free42 Decimal instead of the filename, and the text icon changes to the Free42 Decimal icon. This shortcut now appears in the Launcher Dash and in the Applications Dash (Overview). Copying it to the Desktop means you can click it there too to launch the Free42 Decimal app.

The format, structure, and syntax of `*,desktop` (launcher, shortcut) files is documented at [Desktop Entry Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/index.html).